# Retriving SharePoint list column values with Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-javascript

I have a SharePoint list with a choice column called "Asset Type". The column available choices are "Type 1", "Type 2" and "Type 3". I'd like to build a script that returns (in any way) only the values that are checked and ignores the rest of them. Any ideas how this can be done?

thanks!
Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

You could use REST api to filter list items.

Sample script:

```
$.ajax({
     url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('yourList')/items?$filter=(choiceField eq 'CHOICE1') or (choiceField eq 'CHOICE2')",
     type: "GET",
     headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
              },
     success: function (data) {                
        var listItemInfo = '';
        $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        //to do

           console.log(value.choiceField);
        }) ;
     }, 
     error: function(error) {            
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  

     }  
});
```

Added [this thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax/) for your reference.